# ArangoDB "Spring Data Demo" Tutorial outdated?

Tags: spring-data, arangodb

Like the title says, is it possible the tutorial at https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/spring-data/ is outdated? I'm having several problems, but don't know how to workaround the last one:

1. Part 2, "Save and read an entity"

I get an error: method getId() is undefined.

Workaround: I added a getter in class Character.

2. Also in "Save and read an entity"

   final Character foundNed = repository.findOne(nedStark.getId());

The method findOne(Example) in the type QueryByExampleExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Workaround: I used find by example:

```
final Optional<Person> foundNed = repository.findOne(Example.of(nedStark));
```

3. Part 1, "Create a Configuration class"

   public class DemoConfiguration extends AbstractArangoConfiguration {

Gives me an error:
"No constructor with 1 argument defined in class 'com.arangodb.springframework.repository.ArangoRepositoryFactoryBean'"

Workaround: ?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the demo project on github: https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data-demo

Number 1: They use a getter too.

Number 2: Was my fault, I did try ArangoRepository (of Character, Integer) but forgot that Id is a string.

Number 3: They don't seem use any Configuration (AbstractArangoConfiguration) class in the source at all although it is still mentioned in that tutorial. I think now the config and connection is handled by spring autoconfigure. Though I would like to know how the Arango driver is set, all I could find that may point further is ArangoOperations.

Anyway it works now, maybe this helps somebody else who is having the same problems.

Comment: Use the latest version of "arangodb-spring-boot-starter" 1.0.1.